# My rails app runs fine in development mode, but I get 'connection refused' in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, raspbian, puma

I have a rails app that I deploy to a Raspberry PI, running it in development mode for testing, and then switching to production mode for 'production'.

I have a script for precompiling assets and build the database in production mode.  The rails app runs fine in dev mode, but gives me 'connection refused' in the browser in production mode.

I use puma as my web server, listening on localhost:9292.  I have tried it with and without the '--daemonize' option, and that doesn't seem to make any difference: works in dev, not in prod.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this problem was all about timing.  I found that my Raspberry PI was a LOT slower than my development box.  Below are the times required to precompile the rails assets on each box...

Development box (Ubuntu Linux 64 bit, 160gb ssd drive)

```
time RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

real  0m4.227s
user  0m3.905s
sys 0m0.306s
```

Raspberry PI (Raspbian, 8gb sd card)

```
time RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

real  8m2.129s
user  7m53.790s
sys 0m5.230s
```

So, my PI was working all the time, just taking waaay longer than I expected. I am using Zurb Foundation for my styles, and have found that I only need 5 of the 36 files included by default.  Now, to look at my Javascript code for similar reductions.